# Get the total height of the document or body

Tags: svelte

I am trying to get the total height of the document (not the window). I was expecting to be able to do something like below, but it returns undefined.

Question 1. What is the correct way of getting this value?

Question 2. Why is typescript not giving an error, since it is strictly typed?

```html
<script>
    let offsetHeight: number
    let clientHeight: number
</script>

<svelte:body bind:offsetHeight bind:clientHeight />

<h1>{offsetHeight}</h1>
<h1>{clientHeight}</h1>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/5eb53ab15aae44cf8e256fa7c8f89bc7?version=4.2.7

Answer (score 0):

1. I would probably just use [a `ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) directly (in `onMount`).
2. The property is probably just inherited from the `body` element type, which is being treated like other elements, even though this is a special element which does not support everything.
   Tooltip on property reads:

   > Available for block level elements. (read-only)